# Cannot drag links onto existing tabs in Safari 5.1

Tags: safari

I have become very used to dragging links, from within the browser or other apps, onto existing tabs in order to have the link open in that tab. Safari 5.1 seems to eliminate this behavior and it is driving me **batty**.

Is there a way to change this behavior? Maybe through `defaults write` on the command line, or some kind of extension?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has returned to normal in Safari 5.1.1